# Assigning new pseudo color renderer to raster using pyQGIS

Tags: raster, pyqgis, color-ramp

I would like to assign a new pseudo color style to my raster layer using PyQGIS. I created the following script:

```py
#accessing the raster layer
rl = iface.activeLayer()

## get default style
myStyle = QgsStyle().defaultStyle()

ramp = myStyle.colorRamp(defaultColorRampNames[2])

# set up an empty renderer and assign the color ramp
renderer = QgsSingleBandPseudoColorRenderer(rl.dataProvider())
renderer.createShader(ramp)

print(renderer.shader()) # prints None
rl.setRenderer(renderer)
rl.triggerRepaint()
```

When I run the script, it makes my raster all transparent, not sure what I am missing.

Comment: I have updated my answer to the linked duplicate to include a broader example (retrieving max and min values of raster and passing to `QgsColorRampShader` constructor).

Comment: Or a slightly different approach here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/420407/pyqgis-legend-doesnt-update-with-renderer/420424#420424  I actually forgot about the earlier question when I answered this.